# Dropdown table view with multiple and single selection in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have filter which is done in dropdown table view in an view controller. The dropdown table view contains three section namely section 1, section 2 and section 3. For section 1 and section 3 should single selection and section 2 should be multiple selection. When tapping section 1 it expands table view cell and when tapping on section 2 will expand and section 1 will close the expansion.

When selecting the option from each section should stored even user close and reopens the filter dropdown table view.

**I have four questions:**

1. When user tap on different section it should automatically close already open sections?
2. Table view should adjust height and its position based number cells in each sections?
3. how to do multiple and single selection for three sections?
4. selected should be stored even if dropdown table view is close and reopened.

Here is the code which tried so far all question which i have mentioned above:

```
 extension HomeViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate {




func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if locationListBool == true {

        return 1

    } else {

        return sectionss.count

        }

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if locationListBool == true {

        return autocompleteplaceArray.count

    } else {

        return sectionss[section].category.count

      }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if locationListBool == true {

        return 0

    } else {

    return 30

     }

  }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if locationListBool == true {

        return 30

    } else {

        if (sectionss[indexPath.section].expanded) {



           return 30
        } else  {


            return 0

        }
     }

   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if locationListBool == true {

        return 0

    } else {

    return 2


    }
   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if locationListBool == true {

        return nil

    } else {

    let header = ExpandableHeaderView()
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    header.customInit(title: sectionss[section].genre, section: section, delegate: self)


    return header

    }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if locationListBool == true {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "placecell", for: indexPath) as! locationNameTableViewCell

            guard autocompleteplaceArray.count > 0 else {

                return cell
            }

            cell.locationName.text = autocompleteplaceArray[indexPath.row]



            return cell

    } else {

    let cell = dropDownTbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dropDownCell", for: indexPath) as! dropDownCell

    cell.dropDownLbl.text = sectionss[indexPath.section].category[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle   = .none

    return cell

    }

    }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {



  }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    if locationListBool == true {

        let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
        if indexPath.row == lastRowIndex - 1  {

            tableView.allowsSelection = true

        } else {

            tableView.allowsSelection = true
        }

        }

     }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if locationListBool == true {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow  {

            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            searchText.text = (currentCell.textLabel?.text)
            searchText.text = autocompleteplaceArray[indexPath.row]
            placeIDString = autocompletePlaceIDArray[indexPath.row]
            print("placeIDString::::\(String(describing: placeIDString))")

            if placeIDString != nil {

                getPlaceIDLatLong(placeIDs: placeIDString!)
                print("get lat long \(getPlaceIDLatLong(placeIDs: placeIDString!))")

            }

      //            PrefsManager.sharedinstance.lastlocation = searchText.text
            locationText = searchText.text
            print("locationText::::\(String(describing: locationText))")

            }


        self.locationTableList.isHidden = true

        }
        else {


        }

    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if let previousIndexPath = indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy {
            dropDownTbl.deselectRow(at: previousIndexPath as IndexPath, animated: false)
            dropDownTbl.cellForRow(at: previousIndexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
        indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
        dropDownTbl.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

    case 1:

        dropDownTbl.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark


    default:

        break
    }

    return indexPath
   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
  {

    switch indexPath.section {

    case 0:

        if let previousIndexPath = indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy {
            dropDownTbl.deselectRow(at: previousIndexPath as IndexPath, animated: false)
            dropDownTbl.cellForRow(at: previousIndexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
        indexPathOfSelectedRowPaidBy = nil

    case 1:
        dropDownTbl.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none




    default:

        break
    }

  }


func toogleSection(header: ExpandableHeaderView, section: Int) {
    sectionss[section].expanded = !sectionss[section].expanded
    dropDownTbl.beginUpdates()

    if sectionss[0].expanded{


        dropDownTbl.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 152, width: 345, height: 300)

    } else if sectionss[1].expanded  {


        dropDownTbl.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 152, width: 345, height: 230)

    } else if sectionss[2].expanded {

        dropDownTbl.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 152, width: 345, height: 330)

    } else {

        dropDownTbl.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 152, width: 345, height: 90)
    }

    for i in 0 ..< sectionss[section].category.count {



            dropDownTbl.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: section)], with: .automatic)

    }
    dropDownTbl.endUpdates()
}
}
```

**Expandable table view header::**

```
 import UIKit

protocol ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate {
func toogleSection(header: ExpandableHeaderView, section: Int)
 }

 class ExpandableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

var delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate?
var section: Int!
var collapaseHandlerArray = [String]()

let button = UIButton()
let button2 = UIButton()

override init(reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectheaderAction)))
 }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }

@objc func selectheaderAction(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let cell = gestureRecognizer.view as! ExpandableHeaderView


   }

   func customInit(title: String, section: Int, delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate) {


    self.textLabel?.text = title




    self.section = section
    self.delegate = delegate

  }

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Nunito-Light", size: 12)
    self.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 64.0/255, green: 75.0/255, blue: 105.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}

 }
```

**Dropdown table view cell:**

```
 class dropDownCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var dropDownLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dropDwnBtn: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Here is the screen shots when selection done in cell and after reopen filter selections are removed or options selected are changed, sections are not closed already expanded sections. Excepted result: [image: section with selected][image: section2 selected with multiple option][image: section3 with selected with single selection]

Comment: You posted your all code but does not mentioned where you facing the issue.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of what you have, an image of what you aim to get, and a pinpoint of what is ***actually*** wrong?

Comment: @George_E_2 hey i have updated screenshots

Comment: @George_E_2 can you check it out screenshots which i have updated

Comment: Please include only _relevant_ code in your question. It's disrespectful to dump whole classes and make people read through code that has nothing to do with what you're asking. Please read [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: @AshleyMills thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: @PvDev I still don't understand what you mean by `"Section are not closed when another section opened"`... Can you please edit the image to show what it should be like? Thanks for trying to make it clearer.

Comment: @George_E_2 Now i have updated my UI design .. i want like this..

Comment: @PvDev Now it's clear for other people! Sorry I can't help though, not experienced in this field :)

Comment: @George_E_2 ok ...

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in support for allowing differing numbers of cells to be selected in different sections of a table view.

However, the UITableViewDelegate protocol includes the function `tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)`.

If you read the docs on that function, it says:

> Return Value
>
> An index-path object that confirms or alters the selected
>   row. Return an NSIndexPath object other than indexPath if you want
>   another cell to be selected. Return nil if you don't want the row
>   selected.

So you should be able to set your view controller up as the delegate of the table view, set the allowsMultipleSelection flag to true, and implement logic in the `tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)` function that provides the selection rules you want.

Take a stab at writing such a function and if you have trouble, post your code, tell us how it fails to meet your needs, and we'll try to help you fix it.

Comment: any sample code of it.. based on my codes which i have shared.

Comment: Per the answer… _"Take a stab at writing such a function and if you have trouble, post your code, tell us how it fails to meet your needs, and we'll try to help you fix it."_

Comment: No, I do not have "any sample code of it." This is your app, with your unique requirements. This is not a code writing service. I see you already have a `tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)` function. Now you need to make it return the indexPath of the user-tapped cell if you want to allow that cell to be selected, and nil if not.

Comment: If you want me to write your app for you, I'm available for hire, as I am sure are other people here. Otherwise, YOU NEED TO WRITE THE CODE YOURSELF and we will help you debug it.